# Internet Work; Yet Browsers Don't

Tags: internet, browser, web

My friend is having a problem with his web browsers, such as Google Chrome, Internet Explorer, or Firefox, yet he his internet is active. He is currently talking to me on msn, which kinda proves that it's working, but he's asking me for help and I am unsure myself.

The Error he received says:

```
Server not found

Firefox can't find the server at gateway.2wire.net.

* Check the address for typing errors such as
  ww.example.com instead of
  www.example.com

* If you are unable to load any pages, 
  check your computer's network connection.

* If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy,  
  make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

Any idea on what the problem is? or any possible solution?

Sorry that I can't give more information since I don't know the issue myself.

Comment: Also check answers here: http://superuser.com/questions/38303/web-pages-never-load-despite-internet-access-on-vista

Comment: As you're not commenting on the answers, I assume it's solved? Then: please let us know *how* you solved it?

Answer (score 5):

Update: It would be useful to note that `gateway.2wire.com`
is an internal name used by [2Wire](http://www.2wire.com/) products for web based device access.

If your browser always says it cannot reach it, you have a internal networking problem
(within the home network that is behind the 2Wire device).

1. can you ping to the gateway.2wire.com name?

   - do you know the internal IP address for this device?
   - you should be able to ping to the device IP (since IM is working)
   - if things are right, a ping to name should also resolve correctly

---

This may be related to DNS resolution problems.
Tell him to do the following steps,

1. Open "`cmd.exe`" from "Start->Run"

   - type "nslookup www.google.com" and confirm it resolves
   - then try check the sites that do not work in browsers

---

Also tell him to run these,

1. From `cmd.exe` prompt, run "`ipconfig /all`"

   - What is shown on the line for "`Connection-specific DNS Suffix:`"?

Answer (score 1):

I can't get to [gateway.2wire.net](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/gateway.2wire.net) either. Is the problem your friend has with all websites or just that one?

Answer (score 0):

Does that not point to a firewall issue, software being blocked?

Some firerwalls are too strict when installed, you may need to tone down the strictness!

J

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe his proxy settings is pointing to gateway.2wire.net, just skip the automatic configuring and uncheck the proxysettings in IE(chrome uses IE settings) and firefox, try again.

If he is connected to msn that means that he has ok dns servers.

Comment: A proxy problem in Firefox is indicated by *Unable to find the proxy server. Firefox is configured to use a proxy server that can't be found.* (And I actually wouldn't be surprised if Microsoft has included hardcoded IP addresses in MSN, in case DNS fails; funny people @microsoft.)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not uncommon, reset/repair the TCP/IP stack.

methods are slightly different between the various flavours of Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Indeed, the name `gateway.2wire.net` does not exist, so it makes perfect sense if your friend get this message. Can he go to well-know sites like... `superuser.com`?

Comment: I really have no idea why there was two downvotes...